# ServeCommand undefined array key 0 at requestPool Error in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, serve

I have recently installed Laravel 10 on my windows 8.1, and the server crashes after 2-3 times reload. At first it was an error of undefined array 1 at matches array on serveCommand.php, and after when I fixed that, now I am getting this error. Is it only me who is getting this error, or it is the Bug in Laravel 10. Please someone suggest me a solution to fix this problem.
Thank You.

```
ErrorException
    
    Undefined array key 0
    
    at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php 60 256â–• if (empty($this->requestsPool[$requestPort])) { 257â–• return; 258â–• } 259â–• âžœ 260â–• [$startDate, $file] = $this->requestsPool[$requestP t]; 261â–• 262â–• $formattedStartedAt = $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s ; 263â–• 264â–• unset($this->requestsPool[$requestPort]);
    
    1 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.ph 260 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bo strap{closure}("Undefined array key 0", "C:\xampp\htdocs\upwork_pro3\beach_bo ing_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCo and.php")
    
    2 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Traits\EnumeratesValue php:236 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console losure}("[Thu Jun 15 02:31:00 2023] 127.0.0.1:56527 Closing")
```